# SMIL animation not working when I use with in symbol tag

Tags: html, animation, svg, sprite, smil

I have a requirement to use the symbol tag and reference the SVG elements in the browser. those svgs are SMIL animation svgs. without symbol tag. it is working fine. but if I use within the symbol and use the reference. it is not working. attached the code below. have a look.

Here is the stackbliz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hkeya2?file=index.html)

**HTML Code**

```
<svg style="display:none;">
        <symbol id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
            <title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
            <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath" animationId="chart1t1">
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform id="chart1t1" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-505,0; 0,0"
                            begin="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform id="chart1t2" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-400,0; 0,0"
                            begin="chart1t1.end" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-300,0; 0,0"
                            begin="chart1t2.end" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
                    <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
                        <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710"
                            height="231"></rect>
                        <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22"
                            fill="#009FDB">
                            <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
                            <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
                            <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
                            <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
                        </text>



                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
                            d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                            d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                            d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>




                        <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square"
                            fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                        <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="90">350%
                            </tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="132">
                                250%</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="174">70%
                            </tspan>
                        </text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>


      <svg class="sprite-svg">
                            <use xlink:href="#Chart_IncreaseInAttacks"></use>
                        </svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.sprite-svg {
  height:310px;
  width:710px;
}
```

Comment: How much of this is actually needed to demonstrate your issue? There seems to be some animation occurring so it's hard to tell what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a viewBox attribute to your second SVG element. The first svg element, the one with the symbol has now `<svg style="position:absolute;" width="0"` and I've removed `display:none` and I've moved the `<defs>` outside the `<symbol>` element

```html
<svg style="position:absolute;" width="0"  viewBox="0 0 710 231">
 <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath" animationId="chart1t1">
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform id="chart1t1" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-505,0; 0,0"
                            begin="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform id="chart1t2" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-400,0; 0,0"
                            begin="chart1t1.end" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                    <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform=translate(-505,0) width="505"
                        d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                        id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="-300,0; 0,0"
                            begin="chart1t2.end" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".4,0,.78,.69" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
                    </path>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        <symbol id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
            <title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
            <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
           
            <g id="Page_1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
                    <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
                        <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710"
                            height="231"></rect>
                        <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22"
                            fill="#009FDB">
                            <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
                            <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
                            <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14"
                            fill="#191919">
                            <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
                            <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
                        </text>



                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
                            d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                            d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                        <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
                            d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
                            id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>




                        <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square"
                            fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
                        <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="90">350%
                            </tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="132">
                                250%</tspan>
                        </text>
                        <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#F6F6F6">
                            <tspan clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" x="159" y="174">70%
                            </tspan>
                        </text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>


      <svg class="sprite-svg" style="border:1px solid"  viewBox="0 0 710 231">
                            <use xlink:href="#Chart_IncreaseInAttacks"></use>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Now it's working on FF as well. You had the `<defs>` inside the `<symbol>`

Comment: ok As per the above comment, I tried with multiple symbols tag to load multiple svg's. the first SVG is working fine but the rest of the svg's are not loading as expected. Here is the stackbliz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hkeya2?file=index.html

Comment: I think this is a different question

Comment: Yes, I will create new one